# grep with sed yet rejoin with rest of file

Tags: sed, grep

I have a text file that has n lines - I want to find lines that match specific text and if it matches replace some of the text in that line.

```
foo is good
foo is bad
foo foo is the thing
the thing is good foo
```

-

```
grep "thing" | sed 's/foo/__/g'
```

In this example the only thing I want is to replace foo in the last two lines since the grep matches on thing so my result I want to be:

```
foo is good
foo is bad
__ __ is the thing
the thing is good __
```

Answer (score 4):

Combined both `grep` and `sed` in only one proper [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command:

```
sed '/thing/s/foo/__/g' file
#    <grep ><        >
#           substitution
```

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '/thing/{gsub(/foo/, "__")}1' file
```

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -pe 's/foo/__/g if /thing/' file
```

## Output

```
foo is good
foo is bad
__ __ is the thing
the thing is good __
```

Answer (score 1):

An important part of `sed`'s basic syntax is the *address* associated with each command.  If that is empty, then the command is applied to every line, but otherwise, the command is applied only to lines that are selected by the address.  This seems to speak directly to what you want to do.

"Address" is a potentially misleading term, however.  Although it can be a line number or line number range, very commonly it takes the form of a regular expression, with the result that the associated command is applied only to lines that match the regex, leaving other lines unchanged.

One of the simpler ways to accomplish your objective, then, would be:

```
sed '/thing/ s/foo/__/g'
```

There is no need for a separate `grep`, and therefore also no need to merge the modified lines back into the original file -- the whole updated file will be emitted by `sed`.  You can either add `sed`'s `-i` option to update the original file in place (requires also adding the input file name to the command line) or redirect the output to a new file (allows either piping the input into `sed` or specifying one or more input file names).